# Adding Custom Fields In wordpress add new post page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am Developing a wordpress testimonials plugin.

I created a custom post type also display and working proper. But now I want to add more fields like "Company Name", "Websites".  I know I can manage from this by adding custom fields, but I want to add a separate section for that.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also implement meta boxes which will be displayed on the right hand sidebar the same as you have categories displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Advanced Custom Fields", which is a perfect solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_events_metaboxes' );
// Add the Events Meta Boxes
function add_events_metaboxes() {
add_meta_box('wpt_events_address', 'Address', 'wpt_events_address', 'events', 'normal', 'high');
add_meta_box('wpt_events_phone', 'Phone', 'wpt_events_phone', 'events', 'normal', 'high');
add_meta_box('wpt_events_type', 'Email', 'wpt_events_Type', 'events', 'normal', 'high');
add_meta_box('wpt_events_cap', 'Capacity', 'wpt_events_cap', 'events', 'normal', 'high');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Save the Metabox Data
function wpt_save_events_meta($post_id, $post) {
// verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
// because save_post can be triggered at other times
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
return $post->ID;
}
// Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
return $post->ID;
// OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
// We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.
$events_meta['_address'] = $_POST['_address'];
$events_meta['_phone'] = $_POST['_phone'];
$events_meta['_type'] = $_POST['_type'];
$events_meta['_cap'] = $_POST['_cap'];
// Add values of $events_meta as custom fields
foreach ($events_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
$value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
} else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
}
if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
}
}
add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_events_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields

// The Event address Metabox
function wpt_events_address() {
global $post;
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' .
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
// Get the address data if its already been entered
$address = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_address', true);

// Echo out the field
echo '<input type="text" name="_address" value="' . $address  . '" class="widefat" />';
}
function wpt_events_phone() {
global $post;
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' .
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
// Get the address data if its already been entered
$phone = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_phone', true);

// Echo out the field
echo '<input type="text" name="_phone" value="' . $phone  . '" class="widefat" />';
}
function wpt_events_type() {
global $post;
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' .
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
// Get the address data if its already been entered
$type = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_type', true);

// Echo out the field
echo '<input type="text" name="_type" value="' . $type  . '" class="widefat" />';
}
function wpt_events_cap() {
global $post;
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' .
wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
// Get the address data if its already been entered
$cap = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cap', true);

// Echo out the field
echo '<input type="text" name="_cap" value="' . $cap  . '" class="widefat" />';
}
$events_meta['_address'] = $_POST['_address'];
$events_meta['_phone'] = $_POST['_phone'];
$events_meta['_type'] = $_POST['_type'];
$events_meta['_cap'] = $_POST['_cap'];
```

Comment: Please use above and this one code for create custom fields  in post